# Pygame: Text Won't Appear Only Background

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I have just added in some code I had tried out into my game as a scoreboard and I have encountered an error. Only my background will display. No text or anything will appear. Here is the code I am using:

```
class MenuScores(MenuClass):
    def __init__(self, surface, engine):
        MenuClass.__init__(self, surface)

        self.MoonSurvival = engine
        self.text = "Name"

    def name():

        size = 36
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
        name = ""
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('data/fonts/score.ttf', size)
        background = pygame.image.load('data/images/bg.jpg')

        while True:
            #  readlines returns a list; having this in
            #  loop allows pygame to draw recently added
            #  string; no need to close and open a window
            namefile = open('score.txt', 'r')
            names = namefile.readlines()

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if event.unicode.isalpha():
                        if len(name) < 4:
                            if event.unicode == 3:
                                name += 0
                            else:
                                name += event.unicode
                    elif event.key == K_BACKSPACE:
                        name = name[:-1]
                    elif event.key == K_RETURN:
                        f = open("data/scores/score.txt", "a")
                        f.write(str(name) + "     " + str(self.MoonSurvival.total_score) + "\n")
                        f.close()
                        name = ""
                        self.text = ""
                elif event.type == QUIT:
                    return

            #  create a Rectangle container, where yours
            #  text variable will be drawn
            #  Rect(left, top, width, height)
            textrect = Rect(0, 0, 100, size)
            screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
            for i in names:
                #  iterate through lines from text file (it is stored
                #  in names variable and it is a list)

                #  create text variable and draw it to textrect
                text = font.render(i[:-1], True, (255,0,0), (0,0,0))
                screen.blit(text, textrect)
                #  change y coordinate of textrect; in next iteration
                #  next line will appear below the previous line
                textrect.centery += size

            block = font.render(name, True, (255, 255, 255))
            rect = block.get_rect()
            rect.center = screen.get_rect().center
            screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
            screen.blit(block, rect)
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.display.flip()

    def draw(self):

        self.renderText()
        self.drawHint()
        self.surface.blit(self.background, (0, 0))

        # update surface
        pygame.display.update()

    def _handleEvents(self, event):
        def pressed(key):
            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            if keys[key]:
                return True
            else:
                return False

        if pressed(pygame.K_SPACE):
            self.MoonSurvival.game_state = STATE_MENU
            self.MoonSurvival.level = 1

    def renderText(self):
        # split texts at \n (newline)

        texts = self.text.split('\n')

        for i in range(len(texts)):
            textSurface = self.menufont.render(texts[i], 0, (255, 0, 0))

            textRect = textSurface.get_rect()
            textRect.centerx = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2
            textRect.centery = SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2 + i * self.menufont.size(texts[i])[1]

            self.surface.blit(textSurface, textRect)

    def drawHint(self):
        textSurface = self.menufont.render('(Press SPACE to return to menu)', 0, (255, 0, 0))
        textRect = textSurface.get_rect()
        textRect.centerx = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2
        textRect.centery = SCREEN_HEIGHT - 50
        self.surface.blit(textSurface, textRect)
```

I really don't know how to fix this. The text appeared fine when it was on its own (the def name()) So why does it not work here?

Comment: Please provide a complete minimum example of your problem.

Comment: That is the only required code. Also the problem is right there. My text is not displaying. Only the background

Comment: I was saying that it wasn't minimal. Posting over a hundred lines to illustrate a problem is almost never needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.renderText()
self.drawHint()
self.surface.blit(self.background, (0, 0))
```

Here, you are drawing the text on `self.surface`, then drawing the hint on `self.surface`, and then painting the background image on `self.surface`, over top everything else.

Instead, you should draw the background first, and everything else after it.

```
self.surface.blit(self.background, (0, 0))
self.renderText()
self.drawHint()
```

Comment: Thank you. That was my mistake should have looked more carefully.